# string + number in PHP

Tags: php

I have a code in PHP-

```
$string1 = 'foo' . 'bar';
$string2 = 'hello' + 'goodbye';
$string3=  "abc" + "123";

echo sprintf('%s - %s - %s', $string1, $string2, $string3);
```

Why `$string2` return 0 
and why `$string3` return 123 instead of abc123.

Comment: because `+` is a mathematical operation, so PHP tries to parse 'hello', 'goodbye' and 'abc' as numbers. since they are not, they are defaulted to zero. (which you would have known if you have read the php manual, any tutorial or asked google.)

Comment: The above comment is correct and for more details checkout my answer also If you want to play with `string + number` just go on to the JavaScript and have a try, I think you will be enjoyed a lot.

Comment: Please read up basic php docs available on the internet, e.g. [String operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Also learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

. is the concatenation operator
+ is the add operator

php has automatic type conversion, so will evaluate a string that looks like a number as a number, e.g. "123".

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

So $string1 concatenates as expected, $string2 is zero because the strings evaluate to 0. In $string3, "abc" evaluates to zero but "123" evaluates to 123, so the sum is 123.

If you want abc123 you need to use concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

`+` is a mathematical operator, When you use this in your PHP code the compiler executes the statements as a mathematical way.

You can see by var dumping the second and third variable. Ex: `var_dump($string2); or var_dump($string3);` It will show the output as `int(...)`. So use the `.` for the PHP Concatenation and for the mathematical operation use the `+` sign.

See [Operators Arithmetic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and [Operators String](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

Using the Addition Arithmetic Operator (+ sign) use for only arithmetic operations, not to any strings. So this reason the string can't read and can't type cast so it calculate this value is zero so 0+0 =0, and $string3 is happend same reason 0+123=123